# Vaadin is it possible to have different colors for text items in ComboBox

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

For example in my ComboBox I want the expense items to be colored in red text and the revenue items to be colored in green text. How can I do this in Vaadin's ComboBox component, assuming I'm working from a `BeanItemContainer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with the ComboBox without any client-side modifications. It might be possible to develop your own [Extension](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.extension.html), that would do that.

Comment: Hopefully with time it will be added as new functionality within Vaadin. I would love to have the time to add it as a new Extension but unfortunately I can't for the near future :(