# Vaadin ComboBox text color extension

Tags: java, colors, combobox, vaadin

I am working with Vaadin for a long period of time, but one thing really annoys me: The colorless ComboBox. As I found out, it is not possible to set the items via HTML or to add a color style attribute via ItemStyleGenerators. The last option to do this is implementing extensions as mentioned here: [Question-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948344/vaadin-is-it-possible-to-have-different-colors-for-text-items-in-combobox)
But I have really no idea how to do this. Implementing extensions is really not as clear as possible and there are not that many easy tutorials on how to do this.
Has anyone an idea for how to do this or a good link to any detailed tutorial site?

Answer (score 1):

To realize what extensions are, you must to read about client side Vaadin development. I suggest to start with: [Client-Side Development](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/clientside/clientside-overview.html)

After that you can start to think about extensions.